# Multi join find count subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below tables and have to write a query to get the below output . I am able to get all the columns of the output except for opportunity_published_count . This is basically a count of opportunities which are having value true. 
Current Query :

```
SELECT count(distinct opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id) as opportunity_count , 
       vendors.name as vendor_name  ,
       count(applications.id) as applications_count
FROM public.vendors 
  inner join public.opportunity_vendors on vendors.id = opportunity_vendors.vendor_id
  inner join public.opportunities on opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
  inner join public.applications on opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id = applications.opportunity_id
group by vendors.name;
```

Table Structure

```
vendors
[id (PK) , vendor_name]
opportunity_vendors
[id (PK), opportunity_id,vendor_id] opp_id FK to opportunity , vendor_id FK to vendors
opportunities
[id (PK),opp_name,published] published is either true or false
applications
[id (PK),opportunity_id] opp_id FK to opportunity
```

Output

```
vendor_name | opportunity_count | opportunity_published_count | applications_count
```

Comment: Use WHERE clause instead for the `length(vendors.name) > 0` condition. However, you shouldn't even allow zero length names. Are you afraid of null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Length` is not an aggregate funtion, so you can use it in `WHERE` clause

Try This

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id) as opportunity_count , 
       vendors.name as vendor_name  ,
       count(applications.id) as applications_count,
       count(case when published = true then opportunities.id end) as opportunity_published_count , 
FROM public.vendors 
  inner join public.opportunity_vendors on vendors.id = opportunity_vendors.vendor_id
  inner join public.opportunities on opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
  inner join public.applications on opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id = applications.opportunity_id
WHERE length(vendors.name) > 0
group by vendors.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `filter`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT opportunity_vendors.opportunity_id) FILTER (WHERE published) as opportunity_published_count ,
```

Comment: How does Filter work . My opportunity_vendors table doesnt contain published column . published column is in opportunities table.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand . . . They don't need to be from the same table.  Both columns are available after the `JOIN`.  You can check out the documentation to understand `filter`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html.